# Python unittest receives None, but operator function is returning value

Tags: python, python-unittest

So I have a python function that is explicitly returning a value, however my unittest receives None.

Here the function is seen returning a str value:

[image: execute function return value]

But my unittest receives None. see validation_result

[image: unittest validation result is None]

Any ideas on what is causing the return value to default to None? I am explicitly returning a value??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my problem.

My execute function had a @decorator method that was missing a return statement, so the decorator had the returned value I was expecting, but then not returning the wrapped function containing it, and thus it was defaulting to None.

Answer (score 1):

The code you've highlighted just tells you what the value of the constant is - NOT that it's the value being returned from the method.

Your code returns before the `return VALIDATION_SUCCESS` statement is invoked - look for an empty `return` statement, or an explicit `return None` (or if `VALIDATION_FAILED` or other constants is set to None as well).

You can use the step through / step over functionality in your debugger to find out where it returns (since you've already set a breakpoint). Set the breakpoint at the start of the method / function you're calling into, and then step through the code to find out where your assumption is wrong.